Why does the customized database in Neo4j not support vector operations? The parameter 'database' in the function Neo4jVector is invalid
As shown in https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/24074#issuecomment-2393431417
Using the following code, I can successfully create the vector property paper_embedding for the Paper node in the default neo4j database. However, when I try to do the same operations in my newly created Neo4j database mner, it fails to add this property but the code does not output any error.
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Neo4jVector
embedding_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens")  
paper_graph = Neo4jVector.from_existing_graph(embedding=embedding_model,   
    url="bolt://localhost:7687",username="neo4j",
    password="19841124", 
    index_name="paper_index",
    database="mner",
    node_label="Paper",
    text_node_properties=["abstract", "title"],   
    embedding_node_property="paper_embedding",    
  ) 

How to fix this issue?
Is it a bug in the package Neo4jVector when using the Neo4j enterprise version?
The parameter 'database' in the function Neo4jVector.from_existing_graph() is invalid, and setting the value of this parameter cannot change its default value 'neo4j'. As a result, it always generates embeddings for the nodes in the default database neo4j rather than the set one "mner" as the parameter 'database'. How to fix it?

You say the mner database is newly created. Does it have any Paper nodes with abstract and title properties? If not, your code will do nothing.

Yes. There are 2 Paper nodes with abstract and title properties.
